# How to Email Hash variable data in a tabular format with a Header from Azure Powershell Runbooks

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have a PowerShell Hash variable as below

```
Name         Value
 a             1
 b             2
 c             3
```

I am looking to send email in below format

**EMPLOYEE DETAILS**

```
  EmpName     EmpID
    a          1
    b          2
    c          3
```

How to send email from azure runbook in the above format.

Note: I am using sendgrid to send emails

Comment: I am not sure what is your expectations? You just want to have an auto-order based on the alphabets and numerical values?

Comment: Hey @Ranadip, Updated question please take a look.
I am looking for the format and i am not worried about order.

Comment: Just change the column names while selecting using `select-item` and change it to `Format-item -Autosize`
Mind sharing the piece of code that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I used below script but the output is not as expected

```
$Emp=@{a=1;b=2;c=3}
$body = @()
$body += "<html><h2>Employee Details</h2><br></html>"

$body += $Emp | format-table -autosize

$body = $body | out-string

Getting Email like below:

**Employee Details**


name value ------ ------ a 1 b 2 c 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a HTML body as string array and the first line in that array both opens  AND closes the html. (`<html>...</html>`).
This won't look too good I'm afraid.

I would

1. convert the hashtable into an array of objects using calculated properties to get the headers you want (EmpName and EmpID)
2. sort that on the 'EmpName' property (a hash is not sorted, but this fixes that)
3. convert it to html table using the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet.
4. Finally combine it all into the `$body` variable.

The code:

```
$Emp= @{a=1;b=2;c=3} 

# create a html table of the data in the hash
$table = $Emp.GetEnumerator() | 
            Select-Object @{Name = 'EmpName'; Expression = {$_.Key}},
                          @{Name = 'EmpID'; Expression = {$_.Value}} |
            Sort-Object EmpName |
            ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

# create the complete html body
$body = "<html><h2>Employee Details</h2><br>$table<html>"
```